# Weird Java runtime error - currency.data

Tags: java, runtime-error

I keep getting this error during runtime and I have no idea what is causing it. It believes there is a file missing?

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib\currency.data`

What is `currency.data` and can anyone suggest why this is happening, my JDK isn't that old since we're in 7u17 now.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError
    at java.util.Currency$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.Currency.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.useLocale(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ciphor.CiCompile$7.actionPerformed(CiCompile.java:458)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib\currency.data (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
```

I'm running my program with the JDK environment, I checked my jre7 folder and `currency.data` is present there! Why is it only present in the jre folder?

Comment: Maybe worth uninstalling/reinstalling you jdk/jre?

Comment: @assylias I'm going to update my JDK to the latest version and see if that file has magically appeared.

Comment: I think it is supposed to be within the rt.jar file...

Comment: @assylias Well in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib` it's just floating about in there.

Answer (score 14):

**I got a similar error and this is just to help other people who may fall into the same trap :)**

Error :

```
java.lang.InternalError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/lib/currency.data (No such file or directory)
```

This is because I set the global properties which turns out to be a very un-clever thing to do.

```
System.setProperties(new Properties());
```

The System properties are populated with very important data including:

- path.separator
- user.dir
- file.encoding
- file.separator
- java.io.tmpdir

So basically don't do the above unless you know what you are doing.

If you want to a a property, do this instead:

```
System.getProperties().put("SOME_KEY", "SOME_VALUE");
```

or

```
Map myCustomMapOfProps = ...
System.getProperties().putAll(myCustomMapOfProps);
```

Comment: ha ha ha laughing at myself on what I just did `System.setProperty(new Properties());` :D

Comment: @AnandRockzz , Took me hours to figure out why  ;-)

Comment: It's stupid that Java doesn't give you a way to add properties without clobbering everything you have.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat , actually you can. I have updated my answer :)

Comment: I mean it's not possible to set several properties in a single statement without clobbering the existing properties. Not even Apache Commons Configuration provides anything so every application needs to read the properties file, iterate over the properties map inside a loop and set each one. There really should be a 1 liner to automate this pattern.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat , I may be misunderstanding you, but why not read the property file into a map and do a putAll. Added to my answer

Comment: Oh I think that's what I'm looking for. It violates the law of Demeter but as long as it works it's all good

Comment: ...and `Properties` implements `java.util.Map` which I was not expecting. So it's nice and easy.

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution.
You can add this in your code:

```
System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_60\\jre");
```

You must substitute the path of yours jdk version.

Comment: Yes this was the solution for me too! There's no "tzdb.dat" in the jdk1.8.0_60\lib folder

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It was caused by a Java verison conflict ("JAVA_HOME" was set to 1.7 and the property "-Djava.home" was set to 1.6).

I was using mvn to build the project and in the environment variable MAVEN_OPTS the option "java-home" was set to the *WRONG* value:

```
MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m "-Djava.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre"
```

Just *CORRECT* it to:

```
MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

also check your other environment variables:

```
MAVEN_OPTS
JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that `currency.data` is found in either:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib`

or

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib`

For some reason, when I execute my program, Java doesn't know to look one directory deeper.

Comment: It's under folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib` not in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib`. Well thanks, it helped me

Answer (score 0):

In the old skool days, Sun specified that the JAVA_HOME should point to JDK_HOME/jre if a JDK was installed instead just the JRE.

This differentiation has slowly eroded for the same reason that 'exalator' is becoming an acceptable pronunciation for 'escalator': ubiquity.

At any rate some older apps still assume JAVA_HOME is the root of the JRE

Answer (score 0):

JDK 1.7.0_43 does not have currency.data under lib/, only within jre/lib. That forces me to change the build scripts to use JDK for compiling and then to use JRE for unit tests. Unless there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a webapp deployed in wildfly 10 after installing a new jre while the server was running. Restarting the server resolved the problem.