# Eclipse Juno doesn't start - An error has occurred. See the log file [\.metadata\.log.]

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Juno on windows 7 machine.

Solution I tried -

1. Created new workspace and tried - not working
2. Deleting .metadata folder fro exiting workspace - not working
3. eclipse/dir> eclipse -clean - not working
4. Re installation of JDK - not working

P.S. - 
I didn't have any .snap files

```
!SESSION 2015-02-23 18:44:21.838 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-23 18:45:07.694
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (805).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.

Caused by: java.lang.InternalError
    at java.util.Currency$1.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\lib\currency.data (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 more
Root exception:
java.lang.InternalError
    at java.util.Currency$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-23 18:45:07.751
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 0 2015-02-23 18:45:07.995
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin.stop() of bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:791)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:439)

Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:439)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15823126/2670892

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re_installin Java Runtime Environment(JRE). If the problem keeps, you must change or replace your internal libraries of JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue. I tried with different version of Eclipse and everything is fine now (to be specific I tried lower version).

I am sorry if it is not working for you or you want this particular version only but this is how I started working back after getting stuck.